# Linkable search in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, url-routing

I'm building a basically single page web application. In it's finished state, it will use AJAX where it's possible, but I'm working on it's static http fallback in the event if javascript is not available/turned off.

Anyway, there are multiple things that need to be in the url/uri in order to be linkable:

- order by (first name, last name)
- page number (if paginated)
- search term (if selected)
- state/county (if selected)
- country (if selected)
- order type (if selected)

This would look like something like this using only GET variables:

```
my.app?page=2&order=lastname&country=usa&state=colorado&searchterm=mysearchterms&ordertype=downloadable
```

But since if I'm right the convention in Laravel is to use named routes, so the URI above would look something like:

```
my.app/search/usa/colorado/mysearchterms/downloadable/page/2/lastname/
```

Also, since I'm developing this part without javascript, I need a form to submit the `search`+`country`+`state`+`ordertype` and links for the `page` and `order`, which means that when a user clicks a pagination link or order link, the URL would be overridden.

Is there a simple way to combine all of these into readable urls that don't override each other?

Comment: GET parameters (accessed via `Input::get('something')`) are perferctly legitimate here.

Answer (score 0):

Why not still use GET query sting for search results as you indended?

Pass input from search form to **Controller@method_A**. Validate the input it and redirect to **Controller@method_B** -  with additional GET params array:

```
return Redirect::route('search', array(
        'order' => $order,
        'country' => $contry,
        'state' => $lastName
));
```

The **method_B** retrieves search results and returns the results page, which is linkable because of the query string in the URL.

You can get the query string params with standard `Input::get('name')`.The pagination `&page` param should work with it with the GET string out of the box.